# How do I use a pre-trained PaddleOCR model within code?

Tags: paddleocr

I intend to use PaddleOCR to detect image orientation and plan to use their [Text Angle Classification Model](https://github.com/PaddlePaddle/PaddleOCR/blob/release/2.5/doc/doc_en/models_list_en.md#3-text-angle-classification-model). However, I got stuck trying to figure out how to install it and integrate it into my code (I just have a downloaded `tar` file). How do I use the model in my Python code?

If it matters, I am using WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux) and do not have a GPU.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to create a virtual environment either via [Anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/) or via [Python venv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) and then install the PaddleOCR package via pip. Steps you should follow:

1. Setup a virtual environment. You can follow the instructions from [PaddleOCR](https://github.com/PaddlePaddle/PaddleOCR/blob/release/2.5/doc/doc_en/environment_en.md) to do this.
2. Activate the virtual environment on the command terminal and then install the PaddleOCR package via: `pip install "paddleocr>=2.0.1"`
3. Once the installation is done, you can use this [snippet](https://github.com/PaddlePaddle/PaddleOCR/blob/release/2.6/doc/doc_en/quickstart_en.md#221-chinese--english-model-and-multilingual-model) to test text detection and recognition via PaddleOCR.
4. You can also follow this [link](https://github.com/PaddlePaddle/PaddleOCR/blob/release/2.6/doc/doc_en/angle_class_en.md) for text direction classification.

Comment: step 3 doesn't use angle classification, and step 4 isn't in code